# Problemas de strings y numbers

Tags: javascript

Estoy participando en un proceso de postulación para formarme como desarrollador web, tengo dudas con estos conceptos:

- Obtener un caracter específico de un string.
- Obtener el índice de un caracter de un string.
- Convertir a mayúsculas un string.Convertir a minúsculas un string.
- Cortando un string.
- Convertir un string en un número nota.

Comment: Bienvenida, para que podamos ayudarte deberías postear problemas concretos, mostrando lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te envio unos ejemplos que te pueden ayudar

**- Obtener un caracter específico de un string.**

Utiliza substr indicando el primer parametro la posición y el segundo parametro en 1 pues se trata de un solo caracter, ejemplo:

```
var cadena = "Cadena para buscar letras";

var posicion = 0        

cadena.substr(posicion, 1);   //retorna "C"

posicion = 3;        

cadena.substr(posicion, 1);   //retorna "e"
posicion = -3;

cadena.substr(posicion, 1);   //retorna "r"
posicion = -4

cadena.substr(posicion, 2);   //retorna "tr"
```

**- Obtener el índice de un caracter de un string.**

Utiliza indexOf pues se trata de la busqueda de un solo caracter, por ejemplo:

```
var micadena = "Esta es mi cadena";

micadena.indexOf("E")    // retorna 0

micadena.indexOf("e")    // retorna 5
```

**- Convertir a mayúsculas un string. Convertir a minúsculas un string.**

Para las mayusculas toUpperCase() y para las minusculas toLowerCase, por ejemplo:

```
var mivariable = "cadena en minuscula";

mivar.toUpperCase();   //retorna "CADENA EN MINUSCULA"

var otravariable = "Una cadena CUalQuiEra"

otravariable.toLowerCase();   //retorna "una cadena cualquiera"
```

**- Cortando un string.**

Una cadena la cortas con split y obtienes sus partes en un arreglo (array)

```
var clarga = "cadena de texto que se cortara en varias palabras";

separador = " "; // un espacio en blanco

clarga.split(separador);   
//retorna (9) ["cadena", "de", "texto", "que", "se", "cortara", "en", "varias", "palabras"]

clarga.split(separador, 5); 
//retorna (5)["cadena", "de", "texto", "que", "se"]
```

**- Convertir un string en un número nota.**

Aqui supongo que deseas realizar operaciones con las cadenas que tienen solo numeros. Si es asi debes usar parseInt para numero enteros y parseFloat para los decimales, por ejemplo:

```
var UnaCadena = "100";

var OtraCadena = "200";

UnaCadena + OtraCadena;    //retorna "100200"

var UnNumero = parseInt(UnaCadena);

var OtroNumero = parseInt(OtraCadena);

UnNumero + OtroNumero;    //retorna "300"

var minumero = "10.56"

var miotronumero = "20.44"

minumero+miotronumero   //retorna "10.5620.44"

parseFloat(minumero) + parseFloat(miotronumero);  //retorna 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, te ayudaré a entender los conceptos que estás intentando aclarar en tu formación como **desarrollador/a web.**

Lo primero de todo hay que entender que es un **String** antes de manejarlo, un String *(cadena de texto)* no es nada más que un **Array de caracteres**, ejemplo:

```
//Se pueden declarar tanto con dobles comillas (" "), comillas simples (' ') o template strings  (` `)
  let miNombre = "Daniel"
  let tuNombre = 'Viviana'
  let persona = `Random`
```

Si no has visto los *arrays o vectores*, son simplemente una estructura de datos los cuales accedemos a través de indices numéricos *(los más básicos)*. Para declarar un array utilizamos los corchetes **[ ]** y separados los datos internos por **comas**

```
// Por ejemplo nuestras variables declaradas anteriormente se pueden interpretar así:
["D","a","n","i","e","l"]

["V","i","v","i","a","n","a"]
```

**Acceder a un carácter específico**

Si queremos acceder a un carácter de nuestro **String** lo podemos realizar a través de sus **índices numéricos** como he indicado antes, si comprendemos que en programación los índices ***empiezan a contarse desde cero*** podemos deducir que:

```
tuNombre[0]  //Accedemos a "V"
tuNombre[3] // Accedemos a la segunda "i"

let primeraLetra = tuNombre[0] // Podemos almacenar esos caracteres en otras variables
console.log(primeraLetra) // Tendremos un output de "V"
```

Siguiendo esta lógica podemos acceder a un carácter específico de nuestra Cadena de texto y realizarle las acciones que queremos.

**Obtener el índice de un carácter de un String**

Para esto entiendo que quieres saber el **índice numérico del array** donde se encuentra el carácter que quieres buscar.
Seguro que habrás escuchado o leído que **todo en Javascript es un objeto**, pues bien, un **String** también es interpretado como un objeto y gracias a ello disponemos de metodos y propiedades que nos permiten tratar los tipos de datos de forma muy efectiva. Imaginate como si tu String estuviera encapsulada en una esfera la cual le permite acceder a funcionalidades especiales.

Uno de estos métodos es llamado **indexOf()**, su sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
  cadena.indexOf(valorBusqueda[, indiceDesde])


// Si queremos acceder por ejemplo a nuestra "V"
 tuNombre.indexOf("V", 0) //Le decimos que busque la "V" a partir del indice cero

 /* Nos retornará el indice de la segunda "i" ya que se salta la primera
  al empezar nosotros a contar desde el indice 2 */
 tuNombre.indexOf("i", 2) // Retorna índice 3
```

**Convertir a mayúsculas y minúsculas un String**

Si has entendido que **todo en Javascript es un objeto** entonces podemos tratarlos con métodos especiales, este apartado será mas fácil pues tenemos dos métodos que lo hacen todo por nosotros que son:

```
String.toLowerCase() y String.toUpperCase()
//Ejemplo 
let nombreMayus = "ENRIQUE"
nombreMayus.toLowerCase() // --> nombreMayus = "enrique"

let nombreMinus = "carla"
nombreMinus.toUpperCase() // --> nombreMinus = "CARLA"
```

**Cortando un string**

Para esto tenemos otro método, que se llama **slice()**, extrae el texto de una cadena y devuelve una nueva cadena. ***Los cambios en el texto de una cadena no afectan a la otra cadena.***

Es decir que si queremos cortar una cadena, tenemos que guardarla en otra variable

```
  String.slice()

let tuNombre = "Viviana"
let nombreCortado = tuNombre.splice(3,6) // cortara "ana"
console.log(nombreCortado) // Tendrás un output de "Vivi"
```

Es importante recalcar que el **primer índice** que le pasamos a **slice()** no lo incluye, es decir empezaría a cortar a partir del 4, en cambio el **segundo índice** si que lo incluye, con lo cual estamos cortando desde el índice 4 hasta el 6 que es la cadena "ana"

**Convertir un String en un Número**

Esta parte del casteo tiene muchos detalles y te recomiendo que lo mires con mas detenimiento pero lo básico sería utilizar **parseInt()** a una cadena que este expresada como un número entero *(es decir no cuentan decimales, para ello tenemos parseFloat() )*

```
//Ejemplos 
 parseInt("3") // Retornara un 3 de tipo number
 parseInt("32") // Retornara un 32 de tipo number
 parseInt("100") // Retornara un 100 de tipo number
 parseInt("654") // Retornara un 654 de tipo number
```

Espero que te haya ayudado a dar un paso mas en tu camino, te recomiendo que siempre que tengas alguna duda, estoy seguro que en la **red de desarrolladores de Mozilla** encontrarás la información necesaria para seguir adelante.

[Developers mozilla network](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales)